# Angular 2 How to send a parameter in Observable interval - Continuous upload of data feed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, mean-stack

I want to change the get messages to get only the delta of the messages I haven't got yet. So if I will have multiple users it will each time get me other peoples messages only. I want to retrieve the delta every 5 seconds and append it to the results i have already retrieved.

```
getMessages(){
    let maxMessageId = 0;
    console.log(this.messages);
    if(this.messages.length > 0 )
    {
        maxMessageId = Math.max.apply(Math, this.messages.map(function(message){return message.messageAutoIncreamentId;}));
    }
   return Observable.interval(5000)
        .switchMap(() =>this.http.get(this._domainUrl + 'message?maxMessageId='+ maxMessageId))
        .map((response: Response)=>{
             const messages = response.json().obj;
             let transformedMessages : Message[] = [];
             for( let message of messages)
             {
                 transformedMessages.push(
                     new Message(
                                 message.content,
                                 message.user.firstName ,
                                 message._id,
                                 message.user._id,
                                 message.messageAutoIncreamentId)
                 );
             }
             this.messages = transformedMessages;
             return transformedMessages;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

The problem here is that the `maxMessageId` is always `0`, because it’s initialised outside the interval probably. How can I pass a parameter maxMessageId to the switchMap ?

Is there a better alternative then Rx / Observables for pulling data continuously?

Comment: Can you strip this to only necessary minimum? Btw what do you mean by "pass a parameter maxMessageId to the switchMap" I think you're already doing it.

Comment: It is the minumum to understand the full scope.

 let maxMessageId = 0;
    console.log(this.messages);
    if(this.messages.length > 0 )
    {
        maxMessageId = Math.max.apply(Math, this.messages.map(function(message){return message.messageAutoIncreamentId;}));
    }

the truble is that the maxMessageId  always 0 . doesn't get the data right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your first function that sets up the listener shouldn't hold the messages, I moved them outside the function so they can be better accessed.

When you call `getMessages()` now it will make the request every 5 seconds, process the results, and push back onto the messages array.

What you needed to do is when you run your maxId calculation you need to RERUN it inside the observable. You change the messages array so your max is going to change. You could run it on your limited array (transformedMessages) but I just re-ran it over the main one. This should work, let me know if it gives you issues.

-D

```
let maxMessageId = 0;

let messages = [];

getMessages(){
    // initial set of max
    if(messages.length > 0 )
    {
        maxMessageId = getMaxId(this.messages);
    }
   return Observable.interval(5000)
        .switchMap(() =>this.http.get(this._domainUrl + 'message?maxMessageId='+ maxMessageId))
        .map((response: Response)=>{
             const messages = response.json().obj;
             let transformedMessages : Message[] = [];
             for( let message of messages)
             {
                 transformedMessages.push(
                     new Message(
                                 message.content,
                                 message.user.firstName ,
                                 message._id,
                                 message.user._id,
                                 message.messageAutoIncreamentId)
                 );
             }
             messages = transformedMessages;
             // this changes the messages value, so we should also change the maxID
             maxMessageId = getMaxId(messages);
             return transformedMessages;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}

getMaxId(messageList) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, messageList.map(function(message){return message.messageAutoIncreamentId;}));
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. make sense. Added  on response update of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is

```
   return Observable.interval(5000)
    .map(() => {
      if(this.messages.length > 0 ) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, this.messages.map(function(message){return message.messageAutoIncreamentId;}));
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .switchMap((maxMessageId) => this.http.get(this._domainUrl + 'message?maxMessageId='+ maxMessageId))
    .map((response: Response)=>{
         ...
         this.messages = this.messages.concat(transformedMessages);
         return transformedMessages;
    })
    .catch((error: Response) => {
        this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    });
```